# PySpark: use RDD parallelization's output along with original RDD to perform other operations

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Let's say I have an RDD. On this RDD I perform some operations that output some output.
Now, I need this output **and** the original RDD to perform some other operations.

What would be the way to do it?

Here is my code:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(input)
rdd1 = rdd.map(...)
...
output1 =  rdd1.collect() # output I need

output2 = rdd.map(some operations using output1)
```

Comment: Never perform collect() unless you really need to, as this might overload the Master Cluster's memory. Unless you tell what operations you want to perform specifically, it is difficult to help you parrallelize this operation.

Comment: Correct - in principle, you should simply continue as `rdd2 - rdd1.map(...)`, without collecting

Comment: @MohammedKashif Let me give more details. Let's say I have an RDD that looks like `[['a', 1, [1, 2]], ['a', 2, [1, 1]], ['a', 3, [2, 2]], ['b', 4, [2, 2]]]` (every inner list is organized as ['key', 'id', 'vector']). I want to do two things. **First** I want, for every key ('a' and 'b') to compute the most common value of the vector dimension-wise, i.e. I want to output something like `center={'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2, 2]}`. **Then**, I want to calculate, for every vector, its distance from its center, i.e. `dist([1, 2], center['a'])`, `dist([1, 1], center['a'])`, ..., `dist([2, 2], center['b'])`.

Comment: collect brings everything to the driver's memory. You should either use a `substract` or a `join`.  Most of the time, if you start from the same table, it means that you can probably do your computations using dataframes and window functions. This will be the most efficient since it yields one `sort by key` instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

with window functions:

Before we start, let's convert our rdd to a dataframe:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize(
        [['a', 1, [1, 2]], ['a', 2, [1, 1]], ['a', 3, [2, 2]], ['b', 4, [2, 2]]]
    ), ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
)
```

First we compute occurences:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
w1 = Window.partitionBy("c1", df.c3[0])
w2 = Window.partitionBy("c1", df.c3[1])
df1 = df.select(
    "c1", "c2", "c3", 
    psf.count("*").over(w1).alias("count1"), 
    psf.count("*").over(w2).alias("count2")
)
```

Next we find the most frequent item:

```py
w1 = Window.partitionBy("c1").orderBy(psf.desc("count1"))
w2 = Window.partitionBy("c1").orderBy(psf.desc("count2"))
df2 = df1.select(
    "c1", "c2", "c3",
    psf.first(df1.c3[0]).over(w1).alias("most_freq1"), 
    psf.first(df1.c3[1]).over(w2).alias("most_freq2") 
)
```

then, we compute the distancte

```py
df3 = df2.withColumn(
    "dist", 
    psf.sqrt((df2.most_freq1 - df2.c3[0])**2 + (df2.most_freq2 - df2.c3[1])**2)
)
df3.show()
    +---+---+------+----------+----------+----+
    | c1| c2|    c3|most_freq1|most_freq2|dist|
    +---+---+------+----------+----------+----+
    |  b|  4|[2, 2]|         2|         2| 0.0|
    |  a|  1|[1, 2]|         1|         2| 0.0|
    |  a|  3|[2, 2]|         1|         2| 1.0|
    |  a|  2|[1, 1]|         1|         2| 1.0|
    +---+---+------+----------+----------+----+
```